# Crystal Field Theory (CFT) in $s$-$p$ orbitals system

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, orbitals

> [Crystal Field Theory (CFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory) is a model that describes the breaking of degeneracies of electron orbital states, usually d or f orbitals (Source: wiki).

My doubts:

1. Is it possible to have CFT effect in the S or p orbitals system.
2. Can this theory help to understand the hybridization?